# Sql creating table without using foreign key

Tags: mysql

Consider we have one sql table customers[image]

now consider iF we have a table where their are two columns `customer_name` and `orders_name` now one customer may have multiple orders (one to many relationship) So we have table where  in which we choose customer_name as foriegn key. But now consider we have 100 orders to one customer_name so we have to write same customer_name 100 times. waist of memory.

`customer_name,customer_orders` table is

[image]
so i was thinking is can't we just make table with name of customer_name orders, for examle if we have customer_name  bill so we can  create a table with name of bill's orders, and write all his orders in it, now we not using any foriegn key,

`bill's orders` table is

[image]

and more tables we can create for other users so how it is possible to delete the table when we delete that customer_name from main table. any idea?

Comment: NO no no and again no

Comment: If you want to see bills orders query the Orders table where customer = 'bill'

Comment: If for no other (database design reason) than if you have 10,000 customers you will have 10,000 tables

Comment: the name of the table is bill

Comment: And what if you have 2 customers called BILL etc etc for so many reasons this is a terrible idea

Comment: @RiggsFolly but writing same name again and again is also waste

Comment: and consider if i have not many customers but  have many orders from those few customers

Comment: Correct solution: 2 tables 1=Customer_table, holds all customer details 2. Orders table, holds details of an order and the unique (autoIncrement) key of the customer from the customer table

Comment: You would end up wasting time and effort needing to write the same query over & over for each table - just better to design the database correctly in the first place. A table with you customer names & id's with a primary key & using a foreign key in associated tables.

Comment: Please do a google search on `basic relational database design` before you go any further creating your database. Its not rocket science, but there is a certain skill that you need to learn or you will end up in a real mess in a few weeks

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok thanks. i understand , it was a bad idea.thanks for reply

Comment: You should also break out your products into a seperate table. then link them to an order using the products unique key as well

Answer (score 2):

You solve the issue of wasted space by using surrogate keys. Instead of copying a huge alphanumeric field (names) to child tables, you would create an ID of sorts using a more compact data type (byteint, smallint, int, etc.). In the approach you propose where you create a separate table for each customer, you will run into the following issues:

- cannot run aggregates across customers, i.e., you cannot simply do a sum, avg, min, etc. for sets of customers slicing the data different ways
- SQL will be far more complex with each extra customer added to the queries
- your data dictionary is going to grow huge and at some point you will incur major performance issues that are not easy to fix

The point of using a relational database is to allow for users to dynamically slice and dice the data. The method that you are proposing would not be useful for querying.